# last Monday for not current date

Tags: php, datetime

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last Monday"))
```

show current last Monday.

How can i check this for example for dates:

2010-11-12 and 2011-03-04 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use the `DateTime` class.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2010-11-12');
$dateTime->modify('last Monday');
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DateTime` class [as already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8660043/367456) or just use [`strtotime`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/strtotime) once more:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last Monday", strtotime("2010-11-12")));
```

Or more nicely lined up:

```
$date = strtotime("2010-11-12");
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last Monday", $date));
```

Answer (score 2):

the strtotime function can take a unix timestamp as a second input, for use as the now time in relative calculations. See the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)